# Post method with multiple parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am unable to insert multiple rows in database using Post method in MVC web API. I have written code for it but when i am testing by inserting multiple rows through postman it is giving error. At line first the variable "delegatetable" shows null due to which error is coming. i am not doing database connection through entity framework, i have created a DelegateTable class.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(List<DelegateTable> delegatetable)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var delegateContext = new ShowContext())
            {

                foreach (DelegateTable item in delegatetable)
                {
                    DelegateTable delegates = new DelegateTable();
                    delegates.Salutation__c = item.Salutation__c;
                    delegates.First_Name__c = item.First_Name__c;
                    delegates.Last_Name__c = item.Last_Name__c;
                    delegates.Account_Name__c = item.Account_Name__c;
                    delegates.Contact_Email__c = item.Contact_Email__c;
                    delegates.Category__c = item.Category__c;
                    delegates.Conference_Type__c = item.Conference_Type__c;
                    delegates.Conference_Selection__c = item.Conference_Selection__c;
                    delegates.Payment_Statuss__c = item.Payment_Statuss__c;
                    delegates.Barcode__c = item.Barcode__c;
                    delegateContext.SaveChanges();
                }


                var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, delegatetable);
                message.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri.ToString());
                return message;
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }
    }
```

Json data that i am passing is below

```
[
    {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "Registration__c",
            "url": "/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Registration__c/a3h8E0000009VuVQAU"
        },
        "Salutation__c": "Dr.",
        "First_Name__c": "Test",
        "Last_Name__c": "Test",
        "Account_Name__c": "Test",
        "Contact_Email__c": "test123@gmail.com",
        "Category__c": "Test",
        "Conference_Type__c": null,
        "Conference_Selection__c": null,
        "Payment_Statuss__c": null,
        "Barcode__c": "Test"
    },
    {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "Registration__c",
            "url": "/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Registration__c/a3hD0000001kEfOIAU"
        },
        "Salutation__c": "Mr.",
        "First_Name__c": "Demo",
        "Last_Name__c": "Demo",
        "Account_Name__c": "Demo",
        "Contact_Email__c": "Demo@gmail.com",
        "Category__c": "Demo",
        "Conference_Type__c": null,
        "Conference_Selection__c": null,
        "Payment_Statuss__c": null,
        "Barcode__c": null
    }
]
```

Comment: Please update your question with json that you are posting to your Web API endpoint. If your `List<DelegateTable>` is null it means the json may not be valid and not getting deserialized into object by web api

Comment: Added json data also

Comment: You need to have the Json data formatted as an array to be converted to a `List`.

Comment: Wrap your data inside `[]`.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your Post method and check the delegateTable list has data or is it null? Also, inside loop a new DelegateTable instance is created but how it is attached to delegateContext so I think you are missing delegatContext.DelegateTables.Ads(delegates)

Answer (score 1):

You may try to reformat your payload as a JSON array, as the problem might be that the payload cannot be converted to a List. 
Try this:

```
{ 
   "delegates" : 
    [ 
     { 
      "attributes": ..., ...
     },
     { "attributes": ..., ...
     },
     ... 
    ] 
}
```

Comment: Yes i have made changes in Json format all is running fine there is no error coming  but data is not getting inserted in database